# Forward Many to One Descriptor attribute error Django

Tags: django, view

I am new to django what am I doing wrong here? I want to delete a song from an album and I want to redirect it to the album details page.

```
class SongDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Song
    album_id = Song.album.pk
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:detail', args=[album_id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access `Song.album`, because the view does not know which is the current `Song` here.

You can use the [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method and override it as `get_success_url`:

```
from django.urls import reverse


class SongDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Song

    def get_success_url(self):
        album = self.object.album

        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'album_pk': album.pk})
```

Where `self.object` now is the certain object (`Song`) that you want to delete. And now you can access its `album` property.

*Note*: Replace the `'album_pk'` key with whatever it is named in your `music:detail` url.

Comment: it throws out: 'unhashable type: "dict" ' What seems to be wrong?

Comment: @JMLontoc Oh, my bad. You should use `reverse` instead of `reverse_lazy`. Answer edited now.

Comment: i changed it to " return reverse('music:detail', args=[album.id]) " and it worked. Thanks!